# Error when debugging Flash Game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, typeerror

I keep on getting this error

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>       at GameController/update()[C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Better PW\GameController.as:32]

I have the terms defined, yet it keeps giving me an error. Please Help Debug! TY.

```
 package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.*;


    public class GameController extends MovieClip
    {
        private var score1, score2, year, delay, p1, p2:Number;
        private var phase, game_winner:String;
        private var playDone:Boolean;

        public function GameController() 
        {}
        private function update(evt:Event){
            if(p1 == 1 && p2 == 1){
                score1= score1+1;
                score2= score2+1;
            }else if(p1 == 1 && p2 == 2){
                score1= score1+3
            }else if (p2 == 1  && p1 == 2){
                score2= score2+3
            }else if (p1 == 2 && p2 == 2){
                score1= score1+2
                score2= score2+2
            }
            txtPlayerUno.text = score1.toString();
            txtPlayerDous.text = score2.toString();
            p1 = 0
            p2 = 0

        }
        private function playerRound(){

        }
        public function startmenu()
        {
            stop();
            btnStartGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotohowtoplay);
        }
        private function gotoStartGame(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnStartGame.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotohowtoplay);
            gotoAndStop("game");
        }
        public function starthowtoplay()
        {
            btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
        }
        private function gotohowtoplay(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnStartGame.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotohowtoplay);
            gotoAndStop("howtoplay");
        }
        public function startgame() :void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, gameAddedToStage ); 
            mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        }
        private function gotoMenu(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnBack.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
            gotoAndStop("menu");
        }
        private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            //1- War 2-Peace
            if (evt.keyCode == 37)
            {
                p1= 2       
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == 39)
            {
                p1= 1
            }
            if (evt.keyCode == 65)
            {
                p2=2
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == 68)
            {}
    }
        private function gameAddedToStage(evt: Event):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: Check this line: `txtPlayerUno.text = score1.toString();` Debug or at least trace all those variables..

Comment: I tried commenting out lines 31-37, yet it is still giving me the same error.

Side Note- The script gives me that error whenever I press my "Start Game" button and crashes.

Comment: txtPlayerUno and txtPlayerDous are not defined anywhere?

Comment: @SharpEdge it is defined...in the .FLA as a dynamic text box.

Comment: You should initialize score1 and score2 with 0 in startGame()

Comment: @Cristina Georgescu I think Numbers don't need to be initialized, they equal to 0 when you declare them. Solution is what Andrey said, something is iffy with the textfields. A simple `trace(txtPlayerUno)` would settle this.

Comment: @Marton Pallagi They need to be initialized, otherwise their default value is NaN. Granted, that might not be the issue now, but it would probably be an issue later when he sees no scores in the text field.